# new to cpp , how do I run messagepack?

Tags: c++, messagepack

I am new to visual studio and c++ .
I have downloaded MessagePack for c/cpp and opened the file "msgpack_vc8.vcproj"
it opened a visual studio project with a bunch of c files and hpp file.

now , I would like to see an example of how Message Pack serializes and deserializes data.

so I created a new cpp file called main and copied the example provided here:

[Github messagepack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/cpp-1.0/QUICKSTART-CPP.md)

I built the solution and when I try to run it pops up this window :

[image]

and I have no idea how to run the file , what should I do there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume msgpack.vcproj is a LIBRARY project. You need an APPLICATION project to run and debug it.

If you are using a third-party library usually you would create a new Visual Studio application project, which contains at least a main.cpp with a main function. Then you would include and link the msgpack library to your project.
That's what your link suggested:

> Include msgpack.hpp header and link msgpack library to use MessagePack on your program.

Unless you plan to develop msgpack itself, you probably won't need msgpack.vcproj directly

Comment: Don't I need to include ALL the source files in order to use messagePack?

Comment: If you just use it as a lib, you only need to include the specified header and link to the library

Comment: how do I link the library ? is it in the properties ->C/C++->General>Additional Include Directories ? 
because when I try to build it says : "fatal error C1083: cannot open include file 'msgpack.hpp': no such file or directory" . and I added this file to the Header Files directory .

Comment: For include you need to add the directory, where msgpack.hpp is located to "C/C++->General>Additional Include Directories". In the main.cpp you would just write #include "msgpack.hpp".

Comment: For linking you need to add the directory of the .lib file to the Linker properties as well as the actual lib name